# Why are the results of this for loop not stored in this empty vector?

Tags: r, for-loop

I don't get why the results from this `for` loop are not stored in the empty vector `zz`.

When looking at `zz` in the environment after running the `for` loop, I only see the value `numeric (empty)`, I've read about it on Stackflow and tried the solutions but can't fix my problem.

Is there a solution for it?

```
a <- c(100,101,102,100)
return1 <- diff(a)/a[-length(a)]

zz <- c()

for (i in return1){
  zz[i]<- 100*(i+1)+100
  
}
```

Comment: You want `seq_along(return1)` not `return1` in the `for` loop, i.e. the indices of the vector, not the contents of it.  Within the loop, you probably want the values, but I'm not sure what you're trying to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
If you want to store values in `zz`, the index `i` in `zz[i]` should be an integer of length `1:length(return1)`.

Because `return1` contains non-rounded numbers, this condition is not satisfied. Instead, you should use a proper index, e.g. `1:length(return1)`.

Hence, the following should work:

```
a <- c(100,101,102,100)
return1 <- diff(a)/a[-length(a)]

zz <- c()
for (i in 1:length(return1)) {
  
zz[i]<- 100*(return1[i]+1)+100
  
}
```

Comment: The numbers are not rounded :). If you type `zz` in the consolse, `R` returns the following vector `[1] 201.0000 200.9901 198.0392`

Comment: This might work but it definitely defies all conventions and would confuse most people for at least a little bit

Comment: I am not aware of any such 'conventions', have you got a link? Providing a constructive alternative answer instead of downvoting would be more helpful for everyone.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But yeah the for loop index is conventionally an index at least if you're going to use an index and value in the loop. It's extremely uncommon to use the for loop index as the value and manually keep track of the index. I don't have any links but I'll say this is the first time I've seen this and I've been using R for over ten years.

Comment: I see what you mean and agree that manually keeping track of the index might be cumbersome. I take back the downvoting part and have adapted the answer to make it more in line with common practice.